# How to bind middle mouse to attack ground

Tags: dota-2

I want to save typing 'A' and left click, is it possible to bind to mouse3?

Comment: bind "mouse3" "+attack;mouse1"

Comment: That might work, but definitely test it.

Comment: I wish it was possible... It's so annoying that only 2 of my 7 mouse buttons can be used.

Comment: @Decency it is not working. unknown command mouse1

Comment: By default you can't bind mouse 3 ingame,however if your mouse has more than 3 buttons you can bind mouse 4 and mouse 5 buttons...but that still leaves you with problem of left clicking on target.

Comment: is it possible to bind to another key? maybe by pressing "K" will attack ground where mouse is

Answer (score 3):

The code you need is this:

```
alias "leftclick" "+sixense_left_click; -sixense_left_click"

alias "atkGround" "mc_attack; leftclick"
bind "B" "atkGround"
```

`leftclick` defines the location your action shall take place (your mouses current position).

Sadly i am not able to bind it to `Mouse3` but you can bind it to `B` or whatever you want for now.

Seems like i can only bind normal actions to `Mouse3` like `bind "Mouse3" "say"`

Comment: does not work :( 
unknown command : +sixense_left_click

Comment: can you try to write this command into the console manually? this is an official command and it works for me. maybe you should check your installation by going to dota 2 properties>local files>verify integrity of game cache.

Comment: Still not working, maybe because i'm using linux version :(

Comment: i searched for sixense and found this `http://sixense.com/forum/vbulletin/forumdisplay.php?165-Dota-2-Beta-Integration` apparently it is a software from a company. i guess it is not yet included in the linuxbuild (maybe for licensing reasons)